# Is there any example to execute TestInitialize & TestCleanup only once in C# for selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am new to selenium web driver with C#. I have Login, 20 Test Methods & Logout in my script and I would like for it to be executed in the order I have below:

```
Login (TestInitialize())
Test1
Test2
Test3
.
.
Test20
Logout (TestCleanup())
```

I Declared Login in Test Initialize and driver.quit in Cleanup.

But in MS Script frame work Login & Logout are executed for each Test Method and I don't want TestInitialize & Cleanup to execute for each method.

If this is possible with NUnit or any other frame work please provide complete Information.

Comment: Finally the Script execution should work like Selenium WebDriver with TestNG

Comment: *"Please provide sample code"* That's *your* job, not the job of those who try to help you for free. Usually, the person asking the question will post their code, the current output and the desired behaviour and then we go from there. Welcome to the site! :)

Answer (score 0):

I posted this in another question that was asking something similar. I'm not going to provide you "complete working code" but here is how you could accomplish this...

You could create a class variable of IWebDriver and initialize it in a default constructor. Then just use that instance of the driver for all of your tests in that particular class. In order to quit the diver after the last test has run you can keep some sort of counter or indicator as a class variable as well then in the TearDown method check that variable and if it matches the value for the last test call driver.Dispose()

If you prefer to initialize IWebDriver in a Setup method, still use a field to hold your instance of IWebDriver and in the Setup method check if the IWebDriver variable (field) is null or not. If it's not null then just don't do anything.

Comment: I am unable to do the same. I am adding my code here can you modify the code?   
My Code pasted below:

Comment: I am unable to do the same. Can anyone provide / update my code so that i can proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System.Threading;

// In This script TestInitialize & Test Cleanup executes for each TestMethod
namespace Codify
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest2{
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        [TestInitialize()]
            public void TestInitialize()
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.in");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            ICollection<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));
            foreach (var link in links)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(link.GetAttribute("text"));
            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("Testing");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            string str = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='sbtc']/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]")).Text;
            Console.WriteLine(str.Length);
            string[] s = str.Split('\n');
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s[i]);
            }
        }

        [TestCleanup()]
        public void testcleanp()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone provide / update my code so that i can proceed further

Answer (score 0):

Tests are executed in random order. TestInitialize and TestCleanup are executed respectively before and after each test.

What might help you is AssemblyInitialize and AssemblyCleanup in some cases.

```
AssemblyInitialize() //maybe log-in here?
TestInitialize()
Test1()
TestCleanup()
TestInitialize()
Test8()
TestCleanup()
TestInitialize()
Test5()
TestCleanup()
.
.
.
AssemblyCleanup() // maybe log-out here
```

Edit: maybe *ClassInitialize* and *ClassCleanup* are a better option.

Edit2: I would read selenium's [recommendations in their documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/guidelines_and_recommendations/).